# srcset: define a file to retina desktop

Tags: image, css, responsive-design, srcset

This is how my image tag look like:

```
<img 
    src="img/thumb-teste-270x190.jpg" alt="usro" 
    sizes="(max-width: 20em) 100vw, 
           (min-width: 50em) 10vw"
    srcset="img/thumb-teste-270x190.jpg 270w,
            img/thumb-teste-690x486.jpg 690w"
>
```

For desktop device, I use a small thumb (270x190). For mobile devices, I use the big thumb (690x486). But how can I create a rule for retina desktop use a medium thumb (540x380)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to specify that the 540x380 image must be used on retina, if you just add that image into `srcset` the browser should be smart enough to figure out when to use it:

```
<img 
   src="img/thumb-teste-270x190.jpg" alt="usro" 
   sizes="(max-width: 20em) 100vw, 
          (min-width: 50em) 10vw"
   srcset="img/thumb-teste-270x190.jpg 270w,
           img/thumb-teste-540x380.jpg 540w,
           img/thumb-teste-690x486.jpg 690w"
>
```

There's a [good post on this](https://css-tricks.com/responsive-images-youre-just-changing-resolutions-use-srcset/) as well.